Some pages returning 404 on a newly created Jekyll site
I just refactored my static web site to use Jekyll.
My code is on master and I use a custom action to generate the site and publish it using peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v4. This is my workflow file: https://github.com/asafd1/asafd1.github.io/actions/runs/10999824198/workflow
The files seem to get pushed correctly to the gh-pages branch.
I'm also using a custom domain, but I don't think it's related.
My problem is that some of the pages work, like: https://asafd1.github.io/index.html, and some of the pages return 404, like: https://asafd1.github.io/blog.html
What am I missing?

Can you include more information to your question? Not reliable to use a external link to a repo. The _config file and the file tree are probably sufficient.

FYI your post is in the path /blog/_posts/2024-09-21-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown witch is not expected by jekyll.

not sure what you mean by "not reliable". I gave the repo link and all the information you mentioned is there (including the _config.yml). And the path to the post was created by jakyll gem not me (as you can clearly see).

You do not have a blog.html file. If you want a /blog.html then create the file.
Also your folder structure is not conforming to the documentation. Move the files so that they fit this structure:
.
├── _config.yml
├── _data
│   └── members.yml
├── _drafts
│   ├── begin-with-the-crazy-ideas.md
│   └── on-simplicity-in-technology.md
├── _includes
│   ├── footer.html
│   └── header.html
├── _layouts
│   ├── default.html
│   └── post.html
├── _posts
│   ├── 2007-10-29-why-every-programmer-should-play-nethack.md
│   └── 2009-04-26-barcamp-boston-4-roundup.md
├── _sass
│   ├── _base.scss
│   └── _layout.scss
├── _site
├── .jekyll-cache
│   └── Jekyll
│       └── Cache
│           └── [...]
├── .jekyll-metadata
└── index.html # can also be an 'index.md' with valid front matter


I do have a blog.html file in my gh-pages branch so I was testing based on thst. And my file structure was created by jakyll. Isn't the file layout in gh-pages the source of truth to the site?

one more thing: it works locally, so my assumption was that it's not a problem with the code as it is but in the workflow that deploys it to Pages.
